# Python 3: single custom sorting function for list of dictionaries?

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary

I am working with data returned as a list of dictionaries.  Each of the dicts needs to be sorted by its values, and a couple of the dicts need "special attention", like a custom sort pattern.

Below is a simplified working example.  I have the sorts themselves worked out (thanks to some help from SO).  Example input is illustrated in the "buckets" dict.

I'm trying to figure out a way to "collapse" the 3 separate sorting methods at the bottom into a single sorting function to avoid the repetition of similar code.  Having a hard time figuring it out.  Test code I've written basically just re-creates what I've done here, but in a function :-|

```
# returned data to sort
buckets = {
    'size_apparel' : [
        { 'doc_count': 86, 'key': 'M' },
        { 'doc_count': 12, 'key': 'S' },
        { 'doc_count': 44, 'key': 'L' },
        { 'doc_count': 44, 'key': 'Bazillion' } # outlier
    ],
    'size_jewelry' : [
        { 'doc_count': 86, 'key': '7' },
        { 'doc_count': 12, 'key': '4.5' },
        { 'doc_count': 10, 'key': '6' },
        { 'doc_count': 2, 'key': '5' }
    ],
    'color' : [
        { 'doc_count': 86, 'key': 'Zebra' },
        { 'doc_count': 12, 'key': 'Azure' },
        { 'doc_count': 44, 'key': 'Red' }
    ]
}

# list of all possible buckets, not used here but *could* be used
bucket_list = ['size_apparel','size_jewelry','state','color','cloth','style']

# custom sorting for apparel
apparel_map = ['S','M','L','XL','XXL','XXXL']

for key, value in buckets.items():

    # apparel as a custom sort map defined in apparel_map
    if key == 'size_apparel':
        try:
            buckets['size_apparel'] = sorted(buckets['size_apparel'], 
                key=lambda x:apparel_map.index(x['key']))
        except ValueError: 
            pass

    # jewelry sizes are sorted numerically, but need to be converted to float first
    elif key == 'size_jewelry':
        try:
            buckets['size_jewelry'] = sorted(buckets['size_jewelry'], 
                key=lambda k: float(k['key']))
        except ValueError:
            pass    

    # everything else: sort by doc count descending
    else:
        try:
            buckets[key] = sorted(buckets[key], key=lambda k: k['doc_count'], reverse=True)
        except ValueError:
            pass
```

The try/except is for when outliers are returned in the dataset, which will occur and is totally fine.  The "pass" is because they don't need to be dealt with

Comment: What exactly is the 'repetition of similar code' you want to avoid? And why do things that are ints have to be converted to floats?

Comment: just post what output do you want.

Comment: Also, why all of the `try: ...; except ValueError: pass`? What errors are you trying to avoid?

Comment: Yes, perhaps there is no way to collapse them.  I'm a python newb and I'l still searching out the most correct and succinct way to approach things.  In regards to the float conversion: That data is actually coming to me as strings.  Sorry I wasn't clear about that.  When I sort them without converting to float it looks like: 10, 10.5, 11, 4, 4.5, 5, etc. (the example in the post is a simplified dataset)

Comment: @Robᵩ when using that custom sort, if the key doesn't appear in the apparel_map as noted by the "outlier" comment in the data, python throws a "ValueError: 'Bazillion' is not in list".  It's there in the other blocks just for safety.  It may be unnecessary, but a word ending up in the jewelry size data is not unheard of.

Comment: But, by putting the try/except block around the call to `sorted()`, the result is that you fail to sort that list at all if there is corrupt data. Perhaps you'd rather still sort the list, but interpret corrupt data as the least possible value or highest possible value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can move all of your key-choice logic into one function, and make your loop appear simpler.

Here is one way to do that.

```
def key_function(name):
    # custom sorting for apparel
    apparel_map = ['S','M','L','XL','XXL','XXXL']
    def key(d):
        if name == 'size_apparel':
            try:
                return apparel_map.index(d['key'])
            except ValueError:
                return len(apparel_map)
        elif name == 'size_jewelry':
            try:
                return float(d['key'])
            except ValueError:
                return sys.float_info.max
        return -d['doc_count']
    return key

for key, value in buckets.items():
    value.sort(key=key_function(key))
```

Comment: not sure why my post got downvoted, but this was a very elegant solution and just what I was looking for.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to do it, a bit more modular, maybe easier to read - still haven't factored out the try/excepts but it started looking a little ugly

```
import sys,  operator

apparel_map = {k:i for i,k in enumerate(apparel_map)}
# or
apparel_map = {'S':0, 'M':1, 'L':2,'XL':3, 'XXL':4, 'XXXL':5}

my_key = operator.itemgetter('key')
doc_count = operator.itemgetter('doc_count')

def f(item):
    '''size_apparel key function'''
    try:
        return apparel_map[my_key(item)]
    except KeyError:
        return sys.maxsize

def g(item):
    '''size_jewelry key function'''
    try:
        return float(my_key(item))
    except ValueError:
        return sys.maxsize

def h(item):
    '''generic key function'''
    try:
        return doc_count(item) * -1
    except ValueError:
        return sys.maxsize

sort_keys = {'size_apparel' : f,
             'size_jewelry' : g}

for key, value in buckets.items():
    try:
        sort_key = sort_keys[key]
    except KeyError:
        sort_key = h
    value.sort(key = sort_key)
```